# EJB is null in PreProcessInterceptor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, interceptor

I'm using RestEasy in a JBoss AS 7.1.1 environment.

I implemented for security reasons a PreProcessInterceptor class. The class is annotated with @Provider and @ServerInterceptor.
The interceptor is invoked everytime, which is fine.

Now, what bothers me is the following.

I inject a EJB with the @EJB annotation into the class. When the PreProcessInterceptor is called, that said EJB is always **null**.

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
public class SecurityInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
{
    @EJB
    private SomeEjb someEjbServiceFacade;

    ... some funny stuff
}
```

That EJB looks like followed:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeEjb extends AbstractServiceFacade
{
    ... some important stuff
}
```

The funny part, it works via lookup:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
SomeEjb asf = ( SomeEjb )ctx.lookup("java:global/mySuperApplication/SomeEjb" );
```

Does someone has an explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `@Inject`?

Answer (score 3):

You can not inject EJB in arbitrary class, but only in specified type such as Servlet, Filter, Listener, Stateless, Statefull, MessageDriven beans, Singleton. If you  want to use EJB in other types of class  then use access though JNDI as you pointed above.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [@Stateless](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) annotation to your `SecurityInterceptor` class.

Answer (score 0):

What are 
**Interceptors?**

`Interceptors` are used in conjunction with Java EE managed classes to allow developers to invoke interceptor methods on an `associated target class`, in conjunction with `method invocations or lifecycle events`.

The below class `SomeEjb` should also be accessible by the `associated target class i.e., SecurityInterceptor`.

```
@Stateless
public class SomeEjb extends AbstractServiceFacade
{
    ... some important stuff
}
```

In-order to do that we need to add the `SecurityInterceptor` in the `<context-param>` of `web.xml`.

It should look something like this!

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
      <param-value>
       ....
       com.myInterceptors.interceptors.security.SecurityInterceptor
      </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: If you are using CDI, then you can also go with `@Observer` annotation. [Refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhic.html)